# How to get Concat comma separated value from mysql stored procedure or function?

Tags: mysql

Below is my table and stored procedure to get the list of only offdays with comma separated value:-

```
OffDaysTable
offDayID |SundayOff| MondayOff|TuesdayOff|WensdayOff|ThursdayOff|  FridayOff| SaturadyOff
 1          1          1         1           0          0            0           0


CREATE PROCEDURE GetOffDays
()
BEGIN
DECLARE offdays VARCHAR(25);
SET offdays = '';
  SELECT  offdays =  case SundayOff when 1 then '1' else '' end,
  offdays = case  MondayOff when 1 then
    CASE LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(offdays))) when 0 then '2' else concat(offdays,',' ,'2') end else offdays end
  ,offdays = case  TuesdayOff when 1 then
  CASE LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(offdays))) when 0 then '3' else concat(offdays,',' ,'3') end else offdays end
  ,offdays = case  WednesdayOff when 1 then
  CASE LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(offdays))) when 0 then '4' else concat(offdays,',' ,'4') end else offdays end
  ,offdays = case  ThursdayOff when 1 then
  CASE LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(offdays))) when 0 then '5' else concat(offdays,',' ,'5') end else offdays end
  ,offdays = case  FridayOff when 1 then
  CASE LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(offdays))) when 0 then '6' else concat(offdays,',' ,'6') end else offdays end
  ,offdays = case  SaturdayOff when 1 then
  CASE LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(offdays))) when 0 then '7' else concat(offdays,',' ,'7') end else offdays end
FROM school_information;
  SELECT offdays;
END;
```

My stored procedure returning nothing can anybody help to find out the out result as like:-

```
offdays
 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I think this should give what you want:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOffDays
()
BEGIN
DECLARE offdays VARCHAR(25);
SET offdays = '';
  SELECT  CONCAT(case SundayOff when 1 then '1,' else '' end,
    case  MondayOff when 1 then '2,' else '' end,
    case  TuesdayOff when 1 then '3,' else '' end,
    case  WednesdayOff when 1 then '4,' else '' end,
    case  ThursdayOff when 1 then '5,' else '' end,
    case  FridayOff when 1 then '6,' else '' end,
    case  SaturdayOff when 1 then '7,' else '' end)
FROM school_information INTO offdays;
  SELECT IF(RIGHT(offdays,1) = ',',LEFT(offdays,LENGTH(offdays) -1),offdays) offdays;
END;
```

You need to use INTO in mysql if you are using a SELECT (SET allows a = b).

Comment: Giles its gives me blank return value nothing

Comment: Thanks you its works after some correction thank you very much again

Comment: You beat me to it :) I have corrected the code in the initial post, sorry about that!